# Convert 2D array to latitude/longitude points with given starting point lat/lon and scales

Tags: java, math, coordinates, geography

I have a 2D array

```
int[][] data = new int[720][720];
dataReader.read(data);
```

Each slot in the data contains a value, for that specific coordiante. The location of the slot (e.g data[5][5] is used to get the latitude/longitude).

**I tried to get the location by doing the following:**

I have the following information:

```
    LL_lat = 28.33346126086149 // lower-left lat
    LL_lon = 30.757889519059812 // lower-left lon
    LR_lat = 28.633821527352005 // lower-right lat
    LR_lon = 39.242110331928565 // lower-right lon
    UL_lat = 35.52560518009779 // upper-left lat
    UL_lon = 30.757889519059812 // upper-left lon
    UR_lat = 35.52560518009781 // upper-right lat
    UR_lon = 39.242110331928565 // upper-right lon

    projdef = +proj=merc +a=6371000 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0

    xscale = 1111.1099999999517 // Size in meters for X for each cell in the array
    xsize = 720 // array size X
    yscale = 1088.97060116836 // size in meters for Y for each cell in the array
    ysize = 720 // array size Y
```

I have these two functions I made:

```
public static double calculateLatitude(double distance, double startPointLat) {
    return startPointLat + (distance * (360 / ((Math.PI * 2) * 6357)));
}

public static double calculateLongitude(double distance, double lat, double startPointLon) {
    return startPointLon + distance * 360 / (Math.PI * 2 * 6400 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 - lat)));
}
```

I basically calculate the distance by doing `cellX * xscale` and pass it to the latitude function along with the starting point lat, I chose any point out of the 4 points I have **(represents a square area)**

But the coordinates are being very not correct, probably miscalcualting something?

Is there a better way to calculate it or whats wrong?

The array and calculation:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < arrayData[0].length; j++) {
                            int val = arrayData[i][j];

                            double distX = i * xscale;
                            double distY = j * yscale;

                            double lat = RadarPhysics.calculateLatitude(distX, startPointLat);
                            double lon = RadarPhysics.calculateLongitude(distY, lat, startPointLat);

                            GeoLocation loc = new GeoLocation(lat, lon);
                            System.out.println(loc.toString());

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: what is that? `projdef = +proj=merc +a=6371000 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0`

Comment: @jhamon Its the projection the coordinates are on, I have no idea how to use it. Probably can be used to calculate coordinates by some projection library but iirc there are barely some working ones for java

Comment: Where is the array? Where is the calculation? What is the problem? "Result is very not correct" is not a clear problem

Comment: updated the question

Comment: you do nothing with the array. `val` is never used

Comment: @jhamon Because I don't need it at the moment. I need to calculate the location first, the value is not related to the quesiton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167798/discussion-between-jhamon-and-jony).